# Run PHP function once a day and cache the loaded file

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I have the following code in the functions.php file and I am trying to modify it so it only loads the google sheets file once a day, stores that data, and for the rest of the day the shortcode reads the data from the loaded file instead of accessing the google sheet at each page load.

```
function sheet_value_shortcode($atts) {
    $API = 'XXX';
    $google_spreadsheet_ID = 'XXX';
    $api_key = esc_attr( $API);

    $location = $atts['location'];

    $get_cell = new WP_Http();
    $cell_url = "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/$google_spreadsheet_ID/values/$location?&key=$api_key";  
    $cell_response = $get_cell -> get( $cell_url);
    $json_body = json_decode($cell_response['body'],true);  
    $cell_value = $json_body['values'][0][0];
    return $cell_value;
}
add_shortcode('get_sheet_value', 'sheet_value_shortcode');
```

Any suggestions? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I would suggest splitting the code. First create a script that fetches the google sheet once a day using cron job and store it in a folder. Second load the file via that folder.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? It should not be too hard to use a cronjob for this